# Check my proof - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Still not completely confident with my capabilities in writing formal proofs so I thought I would ask for a check of this proof.

### Theorem

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $T$ and $U$ be non-zero linear mappings from $V$ into $W$. If $R(T) \cap R(U) = \{0\}$, prove that $\{T,U\} $ is a linearly independent subset of $L(V,W)$.

### My proof attempt

Let $R(T) \cap R(U) = \{0\}$

Suppose that the set $\{T,U\}$ is not linearly independent. Then there exists a scalar in the field F under V and W such that T = cU.

As T and U are linear, then $T(x) = U(cx)$ for all $x$ in $V$. Let us denote $T(x)$ as the vector $a$. Then $T(x) = U(cx) = a$ and then $a$ belongs to the set $R(T)$ and $R(U)$. As this holds for all $x$ in $V$, then we have contradicted our previous assumption that the intersection of the ranges was only the zero vector. And therefore the set $\{T,U\}$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: It sounds fine to me but i don't know why you are proving via contradiction.

Comment: You should explicitly mention where you are using the hypothesis that $T$ and $U$ are non-zero.